# Spring REST API, Pass a primitive type to the controller

Tags: java, ajax, rest, spring-boot

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@GetMapping("")
public ResponseEntity<List<ToDoItemViewModel>> loadCategoriesByName(@RequestParam(required = false) String name)
{
    List<ToDoItemViewModel> allItemsByCategoryName = toDoItemService.getAllItemsByCategoryName(name);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(allItemsByCategoryName, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

How can i pass just a primitive type to the controller, here is how my `$.ajax` looks like

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "http://localhost:8080/todItems",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: 'Work',
    success: (resp) => {
        console.log(resp)
    },
    error: (resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
    }

})
```

Now when i debug it, it indeed sends the request to this controller, but the `String name` is always null for some reason, can you just show me what i have to adjust in my ajax request, it's probably something in the `data` field.

Comment: your `data`part should be like `data: {name:'Work'}`

Comment: @barbakani, hey if i try this i get No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present` , so i think it  looks for some other method overload, have any other suggestions?

Comment: along with @barbakini comment, you need to use `@Controller` or `@RestContrller` to get the json data.

Comment: i am using controler ofc... i just didin't copy paste the entire class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using GET Request with request params(@RequestParam annotation).
@RequestParam means that param in request pass across url, like this;

```
http://localhost:8080/todItems?name=Work
```

So, you just need to move data to url params.
If you prefer send data across request body, please do not use GET method, use POST instead. Many web servers are not supporting request body in GET Requests

Comment: ye i start to belive that this is the problem with spring boog, i just cant access this method, if (required = false) isn't present. So in theory if i want to get all items where their catagory id == 2, i should use post?

Comment: @Alexander usually people prefer using `GET` for REST service that just return something. In your case, using query parameters should work fine (so using `/todItems?category=2`). `POST` is usually used for creating new items, where the request body contains a representation of what the item should be.

Comment: Ye men it worked when i used `@PathVariable String name` and   `@GetMapping("/{name}")` , but i was just asking in theory

Comment: @Alexander, usually people create hierarchical structure for requested resources. for example: `http://localhost:8080/todItems/1/subitems/5` which means that  we ask 5th subitem from items. If we need to make some filtering or something else, we add this info in request params. Usually if we need complicated structure of request params it means that we create a wrong structure of resource hierarchy. [about rest api naming](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html)